# How to trigger Loader function of index route (not parent route) using useFetcher().load() in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have these structure of Links in Index.js

```js
// all imported stuff is working

const router = {
      path: '/events',
      element: < EventsLayout / > ,
      /*loader: EventsLoader, fetcher can tigger it here*/
      children: [{
        index: true,
        element: < Events / > ,
        loader: EventsLoader /** Cannot here */
      }, ]
    }]
},


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
      <App />
    </RouterProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

when i want trigger loader that located in **index** route by executing this line

./pages/About.jsx

```js
import {useFetcher} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useEffect} from 'react'

const About = () => {
   const fetcher = useFetcher();

   useEffect(_=> {

      fetcher.load("/events");

   }, [])

   return <h1>About Page</h1>;
}
```

it doesn't trigger it!
but when I located `loader` function in **parent** path not **index**, it worked fine

so my question is, how to trigger loader that existed in `**index**` route(child) of **parent** path?

Comment: What is `"./Component.jsx"` in this context? Where is the `useFetcher` hook and `fetcher.load` being called?

Comment: I'm so sorry, i didn't understand you, but i didn't type so much for code, because i think the issue in the concept which how to trigger index route instead of parent route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`fetcher.load`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-fetcher#fetcherload) docs:

> Although a URL might match multiple nested routes, a `fetcher.load()`
> call will only call the loader on the leaf match (***or parent of index
> routes***).

I've emphasized a relevant section that explains the behavior you ask about. The parent `Route` component is the route in the configuration with a specific `path` property so I believe index routes need to look to their parent route's `loader` functions to work properly.

> so my question is, how to trigger loader that existed in **index**
> route(child) of parent path?

Basically, you can't. The index routes can call the loader function of their parent layout route.